# Proof of De Morgan's Laws

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I wish to prove De Morgan's Laws. I saw the Wikipedia page of [De Morgan's Law proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws#Informal_proof), which seems to confuse me.

Say $x\in (A\cap B)^{\complement}\implies x\not\in (A\cap B)$ which makes perfect sense to me, but in the very next line, they say that this implies $x\not\in A \lor x\not \in B$ which is not very intuitive because if we think about it even in terms of Venn Diagrams (which is not formal, but still), for an element that fails to be in the intersection of $2$ sets, it's not at all necessary for it to not be a member of those $2$ sets.

Why is this implication meaningful?

Comment: You are right. $x\notin A\cap B$ only implies $x\notin A$ or $x\notin B$. $x$ still might be an element of one of the sets.

Comment: The article says $x\not\in A\vee x\not \in B$, if I'm looking in the right place

Comment: But why is it meaningful then also. I am looking for an intuitive explanation. Thanks.

Comment: If $x\notin A\cap B$, then it must be that $x\notin A$ or $x\notin B$, for had $x$ been in both $A$ and $B$, it would have been in $A\cap B$ too.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thanks, makes sense. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be easier to note $x\not\in(A\cap B)^\complement\iff x\in A\cap B\iff x\in A\land x\in B$, so taking the contrapositive $x\in(A\cap B)^\complement\iff x\not\in A\lor x\not\in B$.